# TestInputFileBuilder 'missing' while updating sonar-java-plugin

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

So, i have a sonar java custom rules plugin, running on the 4.2.1.6971 version and SonarQube platform at 5.6.3.

Recently i tried to update the java plugin dependency to the latest 4.9.0.9858 version, and after trying to 'clean install' the project i get the same error on all unit tests:

```
[INFO] Running checks.security.SystemExitCallsCheckTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 
0.001 s <<< FAILURE! - in checks.security.SystemExitCallsCheckTest
[ERROR] detected(checks.security.SystemExitCallsCheckTest)  Time elapsed: 0s << ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/sonar/api/batch/fs/internal/TestInputFileBuilder
at checks.security.SystemExitCallsCheckTest.detected(SystemExitCallsCheckTest.java:19)
```

It seems like the class 
**TestInputFileBuilder** is not found, but i get no dependency error on Eclipse.

Here's a part of my pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
    <sonar.version>6.0</sonar.version> 
    <java.plugin.version>4.9.0.9858</java.plugin.version>
    <sslr.version>1.21</sslr.version>
    <gson.version>2.6.2</gson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-java-plugin</artifactId>
        <type>sonar-plugin</type>
        <version>${java.plugin.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

What should i do to get ride of this error? I get the same error when i try to run any unit test separately too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade the sonar version to API 6.3. This is because internally the SonarJava plugin relies on this API for tests because of this file : TestInputFileBuilder : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/batch/fs/internal/TestInputFileBuilder.java which was introduced in 6.3.

Note that while it is required to rely on this API for your plugin tests, as long as you don't use an API that is not available in 5.6 (LTS) you can perfectly run your custom rules on LTS.

Comment: Thanks! Changing sonar.version to 6.3 did the job. I also had to include the assertj 3.6.1 dependency to make it work.